# Can we draw a $(hkl)$ plane and the corresponding $\vec{G}$ vector in one diagram?

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals, x-ray-crystallography

The reciprocal lattice vector $\vec{G}=h\vec{b}_1++k\vec{b}_2+l\vec{b}_3$ is perpendicular to the family of planes described by the Miller indices $(hkl)$. This means that if $\hat{n}$ be the unit vector normal to the $(hkl)$ planes, then $\hat{n}\times\vec{G}=0$. So we are taking the cross product of two vectors $\hat{n}$ and $\vec{G}$ which belong to two different spaces-the direct (lattice) space and the reciprocal (lattice) space, respectively.

Is it meaningful to show one of the $(hkl)$ planes and the corresponding reciprocal lattice vector $\vec{G}$ (perpendicular to that plane) in the same diagram? In which space is the resultant diagram drawn? Neither is it the direct space nor it is the reciprocal space, I think.